# force https on subdirectory and redirect non-www traffic to www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https, apache2

So for the past couple hours I've been frustrated with my .htaccess file not working.

I have two subdirectories: secure.mysite.ca and storage.mysite.ca that need to be both ssl encrypted. The sites work when I put https in front of the URL (i.e. https://secure.mysite.ca/ or https://storage.mysite.ca/) but when I put http in front it redirects to my root website (http://mysite.ca/). I want to redirect to the https version of the site when someone tries to go to the unencrypted version.

ALSO I would like to redirect all traffic visiting http://mysite.ca/ to be redirected to http://www.mysite.ca/ (i.e. www in front)

This .htaccess file used to work over a year ago but now it doesn't.

Here is my htaccess file found in the root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(secure|storage)\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be putting an .htaccess file inside the subdirectory?

EDIT: Here is the virtualhost config file for secure.fixnode.ca, storage.fixnode.ca and www.fixnode.ca. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong

storage.fixnode.ca.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/fixnode_website/content/Online Storage"
<Directory "/var/www/fixnode_website/content/Online Storage">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
ServerName storage.fixnode.ca
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/storage.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/private key/private.key
</VirtualHost>
```

secure.fixnode.ca.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/fixnode_website/content/Secure Login"
<Directory "/var/www/fixnode_website/content/Secure Login">
allow from all
Options +FollowSymlinks
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
ServerName secure.fixnode.ca
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/cert/mykey.key
</VirtualHost>
```

and finally my virtual host for my root domain www.fixnode.ca.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/fixnode_website
<Directory "/var/www/fixnode_website">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerAlias fixnode.ca
ServerName www.fixnode.ca
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you saying this htaccess code above worked before and now it doesn't?

Comment: yes. currently users who visit secure.fixnode.ca will be redirected to the proper site only if they manually put https:// in front of the URL. otherwise if a user just visits secure.fixnode.ca WITHOUT entering https:// in front then that user will be redirected to my root site (fixnode.ca)

Comment: Typically that won't change unless you made a change to your system. It should continue to work.

Comment: I updated to apache 2.4 recently. I figured that the update broke my .htaccess file

Comment: Yes you may have overwritten you httpd.conf file somewhere and broke the vhosts.

Comment: @PanamaJack How do I give you the credit on here? you were right, apparently after I updated to apache 2.4 from 2.2 my apache.conf file was overwritten and AllowOverride was set to None for /var/www directory. Thanks Man! Appreciate the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have recently made a change to your system, you may have overwritten your apache config file(e.g. `httpd.conf or apache2.conf`) which may reset the options to default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place this rule in both the sub-directories of both sub-domains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(secure|storage)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the problem is not inside the subdirectory. The problem is redirecting traffic from the root to the subdirectory. Currently if I visit secure.fixnode.ca (my website) it goes to the same site that www.fixnode.ca goes to. This means that my subdirectory is not forwarding to the proper document root in the first place.